# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params') at Function.mapStateToProps [as mapToProps]

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I'm having this error message:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params') TypeError:
> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')
> at Function.mapStateToProps [as mapToProps]

I read that I should use `useParams`, but I couldn't adapt it to my code. I use `match.params`, `history` codes. How can I update this codes for `react-router-dom@6`?

```js
const [product, setProduct] = useState({ ...props.product });
useEffect(() => {
  if (categories.length === 0) {
    getCategories()
  }
  setProduct({ ...props.product });
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, [props.product]);
```

```js
export function getProductById(products, productId) {
  let product = products.find(product => product.id === productId) || null;
  return product;
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  const productId = ownProps.match.params.productId;
  const product = productId && state.productListReducer.length > 0
    ? getProductById(state.productListReducer, productId)
    : {}
  return {
    product: product,
    products: state.productListReducer,
    categories: state.categoryListReducer
  }
}
```

And my routes:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<DashBoard></DashBoard>}></Route>
  <Route path="/cart" element={<CartDetails></CartDetails>}></Route>
  <Route
    path="/saveproduct/:productId"
    element={<AddOrUpdateProduct></AddOrUpdateProduct>}>
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

I try use `useParams` but I have this error this time:

> React Hook `useParams` is called in function `mapStateToProps` that is
> neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function.
> React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook
> names must start with the word "use"  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

```js
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  const { productId } = useParams();
  const product = productId && state.productListReducer.length > 0
    ? getProductById(state.productListReducer, productId)
    : {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use React hooks in React functions and custom React hooks. The `useParams` hook cannot be called within the `mapStateToProps` function. Using the `connect` Higher Order Component is no longer the preferred method of subscribing React components to the app's Redux store. Use the `useDispatch` and `useSelector` hooks in the component to access the `dispatch` function and select slices of state. You'll move the logic to retrieve a product into the component as well.

Example:

```js
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

export function getProductById(products, productId) {
  return products.find(product => product.id === productId) || {};
}

...

const AddOrUpdateProduct = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { productId } = useParams();

  const products = useSelector(state => state.productListReducer);
  const categories = useSelector(state => state.categoryListReducer);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!categories.length) {
      dispatch(getCategories());
    }
  }, [categories]);

  const [product, setProduct] = useState(() => getProductById(products, productId));

  useEffect(() => {
    setProduct(getProductById(products, productId));
  }, [products, productId]);

  ...
};
```

Since it's not clear what the exact use case is here for the derived `product` state, I'll just inform you that generally speaking the above is considered a React anti-pattern. In most cases if you see that you've coded a `useState`|`useEffect` coupling you should instead use the `useMemo` hook.

Example:

```js
const product = useMemo(() => {
  return getProductById(products, productId);
}, [products, productId]);
```

There are few exceptions to this anti-pattern, for example one being if you are populating some local state that is used in a form and the user is editing the local copy which will later be submitted to update the source data in the store.